# Why was Steve Rogers' yard so overgrown?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the very end of *Avengers: Endgame*, we see a scene that has the feeling of an epilogue. The camera starts on a suburban street. A red car from the 1940's (which looks brand new) drives by. The camera moves up to a house that has a somewhat-overgrown yard, with untrimmed plants, a few of which are dying. Inside the house, we see that Steve Rogers and Peggy Carter are slowly and romantically dancing together.

I was shocked by the disrepair in the yard. To me, Steve and Peggy would have kept their yard neat and presentable, much like they always keep their appearances neat and presentable.

**Is there an in-universe explanation why the front yard had been neglected?**

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: I don't remember this detail, but it might have been all the tears in my eyes.

Comment: They neglected to pay the gardeners bill. On a serious note I missed this detail but if you think about it.. it could have been a figurative idea that nothing mattered to them other than they finally got to be and how content they were being together  beyond the world around them not mattering as much.

Comment: @Jared, I haven't seen the movie, but I've read all the spoilers :) It seems your comment should be an answer

Comment: It is possible that Steve came to the timeline many days after his disappearance into the Ice. In that time Peggy probably didn't care to maintain her yard and was instead looking for Steve like a good girlfriend ought to.

Comment: I think you're taking the term "plot-explanation" a bit too literally here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

**Agent Carter**

The spin off series takes place without Steve Rogers and happens in 1946/1947 after Rogers crashing the Wing into the ice in 1945 (and in series 2 Carter has moved to LA).

So by the time they are reunited Steve has been away for at least 2 years and his yard is a bit overgrown.

Comment: Maybe it should be a symbol for the missing of a strong man in the household... In old role model women do not drive the mowing machine...